# Changing date doesn't show new data in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react native app where i'm using `native base` for design purpose. I am using `date picker` from `native base`. Also i'm showing different results of different dates which i'm fetching from api. Now, some dates have data and some don't. When I pick a date that doesn't have data it shows blank as expected. But after showing blank I can't get data from other dates which have data. it kind of gets stuck. But if I select the dates that have data,it works fine. Here's the code I have now:

```js
async setDate(newDate) {
    let day = newDate.getDate()
    console.log('date', day)
    let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1
    let year = newDate.getFullYear()
    day = String(day).length > 1 ? day : '0' + day
    month = String(month).length > 1 ? month : '0' + month
    let fullDate = 'https://myapi'+year+month+day
    await fetch(fullDate, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('new', response)
        if(response === null){
          this.setState({ 
            tableData1: [],
            tableData2: [],
            tableData3: [],
          })
        } else {
        const first = response.First
        this.setState({ tableData1: first })
        const second = response.Special
        this.setState({ tableData2: second })
        const third = response.Consolidation
        this.setState({ tableData3: third })
        }
      })
  }
```

What can I do to get data as usual after selecting a date which doesn't have any value?

Comment: If you console log `response` within the `else` statement, what is the output? Also, error aside, you can trim that part down quite a lot: `this.setState({tableData1: response.First, tableData2: response.Special, tableData3: response.Consolidation})` - with your current implementation that block will cause a re-render 3 times

Comment: If I console log the response in else it shows the data if that date has data. But  the problem is that if the response is undefined and it show blank, then after that it shows no data even if the date has data . Can you tell what to do @AdamRoberts

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite surprised you're not receiving any errors here in console or on screen - are you testing on a device or simulator?

`if(response === null)` is your problem, `undefined === null` evaluates to false, so you're pushing into your else statement and trying to access `response.First` etc which is `undefined` and will cause an error to throw - this is why things get 'stuck'.

You can simplify your check and, as mentioned in my comment, the `if` `else` could be cleaned up quite a bit as you don't need to assign data from the `response` object to variables because you're not re-using them - and your multiple calls to `setState` will cause three re-renders of the component.

Some examples of how concise this block could be. I'll explain what I'm doing as I'm unaware of your experience and other readers may be less experienced than yourself:

```
if(!response)
  this.setState({tableData1: [], tableData2: [], tableData3: []})
else 
  this.setState({
    tableData1: response.First, 
    tableData2: response.Special, 
    tableData3: response.Consolidation
})
```

A simple `if(!response)` check to fix the error, `setState` being merged into one call and values being pulled directly from the response object. You'll notice i've omitted the curly braces from both the `if` and `else` blocks as they are both single statement blocks.

Or you could take it one step further:

```
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({
        tableData1: response.First          ? response.First         : [],
        tableData2: response.Special        ? response.Special       : [],
        tableData3: response.Consolidation  ? response.Consolidation : []
      })
}
```

Here we combine into a single `setState` call, using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to assign each piece of state to data from the `response` object, or to an empty array. You'll notice each condition is based on `response.key` instead of just `response` - this is safer and less likely to cause errors (unless you're absolutely certain there can be no situation in which `response` contains some, but not all, of those keys)